# Can I have a file field in an input form?

Tags: forms, haskell, yesod

I need to be able to automatically upload a file plus some related data to my Yesod server.
I thought the best way to do it was using input-forms.

However, input forms don't seem to allow file fields.

1. Am I correct or is there a way to use fileAFormReq inside an input form?
2. If there is no such way then What will be the best strategy to follow (a.k.a. how to allow the server to accept files that are being sent by a script from a different machine, while having no real need to display a form at any point)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about [lookupFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/1.1.2.1/doc/html/Yesod-Request.html#v%3alookupFile)?

(see [What is the IForm equivalent to fileAFormOpt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811776/what-is-the-iform-equivalent-to-fileaformopt/12817924))

Answer (score 0):

Forms allow `<input type="file" />` , is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not exactly, Yesod allows for coding the form in Haskell and I'm looking for the Haskell syntax that will get interpreted to this result (as well as the automatic parsing of responses that gets generated etc.)