# What is the IForm equivalent to fileAFormOpt?

Tags: haskell, file-upload, yesod

I want to use runInputPost on an existing form with a file input tag.  fileAFormOpt exists for AForms, but how can I do the same with an IForm since there is no fileField type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [`lookupFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/1.1.2.1/doc/html/Yesod-Request.html#v%3alookupFile) for that use case.